# Twitch Bot Game using tmi.js I'd love some help on my array (winner)

Tags: javascript, bots, twitch

As far as I understand in an array, there's a zero? So everytime a zero comes out as the "winner," there is no username to call out and it will tell the chat that undefined has won? How do I make it so there is always one winner?

```
    const entries = {};
client.on('message', (channel, user, message, self) => {
    if(self) return;
    const entriesArr = Object.values(entries);
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * entriesArr.length);
    const winner = entriesArr [randomNum];
    if(message.toLowerCase() === '!join') {
        entries[user.username] = user.username;
    }
});
```

Here is the output message that should display the winner.
Which works, but needs to never show undefined won.

```
setTimeout(() => {
            client.action(TwitchHost, `"Looks like ${winner} walks out with the valuables! What happened to the others..?"`);
        }, 2500);
```

Comment: run some code asking `if(winner==undefined){console.log(entriesArr.length)}` because i suspect that when `undefined` is a winner, that `entries` is empty and therefore `entriesArr` is empty

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to have not solved the problem completely, as having a winner all the time. But.... atleast now I can make a custom message saying that there were no survivors in the game. Which is a good thing! Thanks!

Comment: bru im trying to help you.. I don't have your computer in front of me so I'm trying to determine where the `undefined` trouble starts.. remember you are the one who came for help so ease me up with the haugtiness

Comment: My apologies, I didn’t mean it in a rude or haugtiness way. Just that your piece of code brought me on that path, which I liked. Sorry. When I had put in your code it didn’t change anything. No errors either. So I made it into a message, if (winner = undefined) and then a message.

Comment: lol that's ok.. btw was the entriesArr.length 0 when winners is undefined?

Comment: Ah yes, now that I look and run it again with the code you gave me it did show me a 0 in the console. I must've overlooked that before.

Comment: alright therefore u can't depend on there always to be things in the entries object

Comment: Is there a way to filter out the 0? Or something else that would make something like described possible.

Comment: that `0` means that there is nothing from the `entriesArr` array to get and the math for the empty array would make `randNum`=`0` but `entriesArr[0]`==`undefined`.. so your best option is indeed to say "there is no winner" or something like that

Comment: Ah I see now, hmm.. Thank you, very much appreciate your help. I'm pretty new to working with JS, it's still challenging, but fun!

Answer (score -3):

The problem is in your

```
const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * entriesArr.length)
```

SB

```
const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * entriesArr.length +1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).